# how to create auto running query in laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I have DB and I need to change its status column after 30 days. that mean one data row(post) running 30 days live. after 30 days that data automatically disable. so what is the method to do that.

my DB columns

```
id
gender
description
status
created_at
EXP_Date
```

I need to generate EXP_date automatically.

`created_at +30 days`

after that

```
if current date = EXP_Date  (how to setup query run without admin involving)
```

status column update as EXPIRED

so How I can do that. help me.

Comment: use laravel [task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel Task scheduling to run job daily check expire date.

Document: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/scheduling

Step 1: Create a job for checking expire date.

Step 2: Add schedule job to app/Console/Kernel.php `$schedule->job(new CheckExpire)->daily();`

Step 3: Run schedule `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`